# Can't apply group_by in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse

I'm trying to group the generated data of the user based on their choices. Basically, I want the user to have a copy of the "raw" data they generated then show them some summary using `group_by` and  a plot which will be activated by click on a button.

This is the part where I keep getting an error.

````
                        
  Market_Data <- group_by_(Data, `Market Name`, Year, Month) %>%
                 summarise(Monthly_Price = Price)
                 
  output$MarketPlot <- renderPlot({
              ggplot(Market_Data, mapping = aes(x = Month, y = Monthly_price, color = Commodity)) +
              geom_line(stat = "identity") +
              ylim(min(Market_Data$Price), max(Market_Data$Price))}) ```

#Error Message#
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')"
  54: group_by_
  50: server [#8]
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')"
````

I've tried searching for similar scenario but I don't think I've seen one. Appreciate your help. I also forgot to mention that my Data is reactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Market_Data <- Data %>% group_by(...)`

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that I already tried this method but it doesn't seem to work. I also would like to add that my Data is reactive.

Comment: Without a sample dataframe it is hard to diagnose your exact problem. For reactive data frame, you can try `Market_Data <- Data() + group_by(…)`, and that should be inside a `observe()` or `observeEvent()`

Comment: Hi, that actually solved my problem. I forgot to include the brackets when calling my reactive data. Thank you very much.